# What is the name of a polynomial with 1 as the leading coefficient?

Tags: polynomials, terminology

Looking for roots of a polynomial, it is often the case to see all polynomials reduced / transfromed (?) from the general form

$$a_nx^n+\cdots+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$$

to

$$x^n +\cdots+a'_2x^2+a'_1x+a'_0$$

because it doesn't affect the result.

The [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem), likewise, makes reference to linear forms as $(x-r_i)$ irreducible binomials, in which the coefficient for $x$ is $1.$

Comment: monic polynomials

Comment: Thank you. Yes, from Wikipedia, "In algebra, a monic polynomial is a single-variable polynomial (that is, a univariate polynomial) in which the leading coefficient (the nonzero coefficient of highest degree) is equal to 1." I thought "monic" simply meant that there was only one variable.

Comment: What do you call a polynomial with two variables and 1 as the leading coefficient?

Comment: 2 variables, or 2 terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A polynomial whose leading coefficient is 1 is called **monic**.

Comment: Applies only to an univariate polynomial.